# JOOQ/SQL Error: Long random string "cannot be read as a timestamp"

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector, jooq

This is the error:

```
Value '12ûDEVûûûûûûûûûûûûûûûûûûUnkownûûûûûûûRunningûûUnknownUnknownû1102008-11-11 00:00:00ûû2û0ûûû0000-00-00 00:00:00ûûûûûûû can not be represented as a java.sql.timestamp
```

All I'm trying to do is:

```
String result=create.select().from(VC_INFO_VEHICLE).limit(perPage).offset(perPage*page).fetch().formatJSON();
System.out.println(result);
```

Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks.

Comment: You should include information on the table structure of `VC_INFO_VEHICLE` and the entire code of setting up the connection (`create`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is not a timestamp. 0000-01-01 00:00:00 is the true 0 timestamp.